# Reference to study the infinite-dimensional representations of ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, mathematical-physics

I'm aware that the finite dimensional irreducible representations of the universal cover of the Lorentz group, ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, can be found in terms of angular momentum representations. The usual trick is to complexify the Lorentz algebra and recognize it as a direct sum of two complexified ${\frak su}(2)$ algebras. We then construct representations of ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ by picking two irreducible representations of angular momentum indexed by spins $A$ and $B$. This results in the $(A,B)$ representations of the Lorentz group. In particular this classifies the various fields according to their behavior under Lorentz transformations.

Now, I'm aware that we can also study the infinite-dimensional unitary representations of ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. This is in particular mentioned in the Wikipedia page on [representations of the Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Infinite-dimensional_unitary_representations).

I'm interested in understanding these infinite-dimensional unitary representations of ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. In particular what are the irreducible ones and how the reducible ones are expressed in terms of these. Another question that I have in mind is how these relate to the ones we find in Wigner's classification of relativistic particles.

In that case we study representations of the *Poincaré group* and we do so by first and foremost *diagonalizing the translations*. After that we find how the Lorentz group is represented, so all these spaces we find in Wigner's classification carry in particular unitary representations of ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. I wonder how these relate to the "principal series" mentioned in Wikipedia's page.

Given this description of what I'm looking for, what would be a good reference to study all of that? I'm looking for a text accessible to physicists.

Comment: $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the Lorentz group in a $3+1$-dimensional spacetime. $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the Lorentz group in $2+1$-dimensional spacetime. They were both treated in Bargmann's original article, so the two examples are reasonably close. Maybe you could start here http://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/minicourses/sl2/